# c# enum in constructor

Tags: c#, enums, constructor, interface

Currently I am working on a student system register for practicing C#. i am trying to add an Enum in the constructor but get the error: Enum does not contain a definition for JobPosition. I have absolutely no clue about what could be wrong and tried different things. is there someone that knows what the problem is?

Code for adding a teacher:

```
 //Begin adding a Teacher
        private void btnNewTeacher_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtEc.Text == "" || txtAge.Text == "" || txtName.Text == "" || txtPcn.Text == "" || txtYearAtSchool.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please fill in all the required information");
            }
            else
            {
                //Check if pcn is used, if not add student
                if (administrationTeacher.GetTeacher(Convert.ToInt32(txtPcn.Text)) == null
                && administrationStudent.GetStudent(Convert.ToInt32(txtPcn.Text)) == null)
                {
                    administrationTeacher.AddTeacher(new Teacher(Enum.JobPosition.JUNIOR_Teacher,  Convert.ToInt32(txtEc.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text), txtName.Text, 
                        Convert.ToInt32(txtPcn.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtYearAtSchool.Text)));

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The pcn for this student is already in use, " +
                        "please pick another one");
                }
            }
        }
```

Code for teacher:

```
public JobPosition jobPosition { get; private set; }
        private double salary;

        public Teacher(JobPosition jobPosition, double salary, int age, string name, int pcn, int yearAtSchool)
            : base(age, name, pcn, yearAtSchool)
        {
            this.jobPosition = jobPosition;
            this.salary = salary;
        }
```

JobPosition interface code:

```
public enum JobPosition //Enum represents a group of constants.
    {
        JUNIOR_TEACHER,
        TEACHER1,
        TEACHER2,
        TEACHER3,
        COORDINATOR,
        DIRECTOR
    }
```

Comment: Why Enum.JobPosition.JUNIOR_Teacher? Just JobPosition.JUNIOR_Teacher, surely? (note: JUNIOR_Teacher may be unusual as a name, too)

Comment: I don't think you understand Enums, this may help. [Enumeration types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen the code for declaring your `JobPosition` enum, but most probably you don't need the piece `"Enum."` in the following line:

```
administrationTeacher.AddTeacher(new Teacher(Enum.JobPosition.JUNIOR_Teacher,  Convert.ToInt32(txtEc.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text), txtName.Text,
```

So, you need something like this

```
administrationTeacher.AddTeacher(new Teacher(JobPosition.JUNIOR_Teacher,  Convert.ToInt32(txtEc.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text), txtName.Text,
```

P.S.: Don't forget to add using in the beginning of the file.

```
using Here.Goes.Your.Enum.Namespace;
```